# my asp.net app session working in my local system , when I deploy on the remote server it is not working?

Tags: asp.net

Hello friends help me,

I have my asp.net web application running locally, I have session variable, If I test any number of times locallay it is working, But When I deploy on remote server it is not working  means no session value, session is empty,

```
 <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1440">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Please can any one give me solutions?

Regards
Ram.

Comment: Is the application running on Web Farm or Web Garden? Otherwise, you do not even need to include the above SessionState tag in web.config if you use InProc.

Comment: Hello Win, Thanks for your reply, Iam using asp.net webform to store my webform data in session. in my local system it is working fine, but when I deployed it remotely, My session variable is null, I did not have any session, is there any other way to try, or store webform data and retrieve when needed[ i do not want database]

Answer (score 0):

Not enough Rep to leave a comment, so I'll ask here.  Is the remote server(s) load balanced?  If so, your first request may be creating the session variable on Server 1, but the next request may go to Server 2, where the session variable does not exist.

You may want to consider a different [Session State Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: Hello SteveR,Thank you very much for your reply, My server is windows 2012 server 64bit very fast configuration.located in london.Iam uploding from bangalore india. Now Iam using session mode- inproc, I will change using different type session mode and come back in case any error. is there anything do i need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Now it is working, due to Server Ip address I got exception when Updating my database with session[username]. I thought my session is not working, actually my session is working, it is the web service API has restriction with ipaddress.Thats why I got the invalid session error.

my client papercut, and ogone payment gateway find these reason and informed me.Now it is working fine.

I thank you all the people spend time for me.
thanking you for your support